# Strange UriFormatException when using mono

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono, screen, xmlreader

I'm currently working on a project which has to run on mono.
Normally, everything works just fine. But when I try to run it in a separate screen on my ubuntu 14.04 server, it won't start after crashing once. The error that occurs is the following:

```
System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid.
  at System.Uri.Parse (UriKind kind, System.String uriString) <0x40141e70 + 0x000b3> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Uri.ParseUri (UriKind kind) <0x40141d50 + 0x00023> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Uri..ctor (System.String uriString, Boolean dontEscape) <0x401459e0 + 0x001b7> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Uri..ctor (System.String uriString) <0x401459b0 + 0x00013> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Xml.XmlResolver.ResolveUri (System.Uri baseUri, System.String relativeUri) <0x401403f0 + 0x0010b> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.ResolveUri (System.Uri baseUri, System.String relativeUri) <0x401403c0 + 0x00017> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl..ctor (System.String uriStr, System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings settings, System.Xml.XmlParserContext context, System.Xml.XmlResolver uriResolver) <0x4013e610 + 0x00060> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings.CreateReader (System.String inputUri, System.Xml.XmlParserContext inputContext) <0x4013e4a0 + 0x0008f> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Xml.XmlReader.Create (System.String inputUri, System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings settings, System.Xml.XmlParserContext inputContext) <0x4013e420 + 0x0005f> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Xml.XmlReader.Create (System.String inputUri, System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings settings) <0x4013e3c0 + 0x00013> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Project.Server.Settings..ctor () <0x4013c1f0 + 0x0006f> in <filename unknown>:0
```

This seems very strange to me, as the code that produces the error is the following:

```
private XDocument configFile;

    public Settings()
    {
        var readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings { CheckCharacters = false };
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("config.xml", readerSettings))
        {
            configFile = XDocument.Load(reader);
        }
    }
```

As mentioned before, everything works just fine when run the first time. But after it crashed once, it won't start and crashes with this error. More strangely, I can fix the problem by terminating the screen and making a new one and running the exact same command.

Has anybody encountered something like this before? Is this something that can be prevented?

Comment: Which version of Mono do you use? Use `mono --version` to check. You have to use the latest which reused Microsoft implementation.

Comment: @LexLi I am using Stable 4.2.1.102/6dd2d0d. I ran apt-get update and upgrade, I'll see how it behaves now.